# Match case - Invalid syntax with Spyder

Tags: python, match, spyder

I am using Spyder 5.3.1 and Python 3.10.4 within a virtual environment, on Windows 10.
I know that with Python 3.10 came the `match` statement.

However, whenever I use the `match` keyword inside a script, the following error appears:

```
Code Analysis
Invalid syntax (pyflakes E)
```

But I can run the script correctly without any problem.
So what can be the issue here?

Moreover, if I try directly in the IPython console, the `match` keyword is immediately recognized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not so much an issue with Spyder as it is with the Pyflakes system it uses for linting code.

`match` is a new (soft) keyword in Python 3.10.  [Pyflakes 2.4.0](https://pypi.org/project/pyflakes/) only supports up to Python 3.8 currently.

[Pyflakes 2.5.0](https://github.com/PyCQA/pyflakes/issues/700) is not out yet, but will cover up to Python 3.11, and should lint the new `match` keyword properly.

Comment: So I will wait for Pyflakes 2.5.0 release, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since this still is an issue, note that there is a workaround to get rid of the "invalid syntax error" by adding this comment after the "match"

```
match ... # noqa
```

Was pointed out on Github here: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/17436#issuecomment-1059806705